# Line graph with dynamic data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, codeigniter, canvasjs

I need to display data in *line graph*. **$totalProfit** has all the values on yearly basis. I just need to push this data in view page. then call **ajax** to display line graph. Help me out with this.

```
$graph = array();
    for($i = 0; $i< count($mainArray); $i++)
    {
        $totalProfit = $mainArray[$i]['clientPayroll'] - ($mainArray[$i]['companyPayroll'] + $mainArray[$i]['supplierPayroll']);
        array_push($graph, array('x'=>$i, 'y'=>$totalProfit));
    }
```

output for $graph:

```
0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => int 0
      'y' => float -3996.94
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => int 1
      'y' => float -24.67
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => int 2
      'y' => float -3.87
```

Help me to represent it to view page.
This is my **View** page.

```
    <script>
      function callMethod(){
      $.ajax({                          
       url:'https://localhost:8080/supply_chain_historical_analysis/'
                   }, 
                  function(res){
                  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {            
                     title:{
                     text: ""              
                       },

                         data: res,
                           { //dataSeries - second quarter

                            type: "line",
                            name: "Display Data",                
                            dataPoints: 
                          }
                          ]
                        });

                      chart.render();

      })
    }
                </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
      </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Check the console of your browser and look for error message if any exists.

Comment: I just updated the new data in the above file. Please have a look. @Beevk

Comment: I found the answer.